# python - is it possible to map data and make a vector matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, mapping

i am still a new student starting to learn python and programming. 
and here is my data

```
  Doc1              Doc2
 class1  numid     class2 numid
  doc1a   d112       012  d112
  doc1a   d212       013  d212
  doc1a   d312       013  d312
  doc1b   d412       011  d312
  doc1b   d412       011  d412
```

I would like to merge them and see the result as

```
           d112 d212 d312 d412 
doc1  doc2
doc1a  012   1   0   0   0
doc1a  013   0   1   1   0
doc1b  011   0   0   1   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, using [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) and [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
cols = ['class1', 'class2']
>>> pd.get_dummies(pd.merge(df, df2, how='outer').set_index(cols), prefix='', prefix_sep='')\
    .drop_duplicates()                                                         \
    .groupby(cols)                                                             \
    .sum()
```

Outputs

```
                 numid_d112   numid_d212    numid_d312    numid_d412
class1  class2              
doc1a   12       1            0             0             0
        13       0            1             1             0
doc1b   11       0            0             0             1
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but when i try with a data set that contains 100rows, some data is missing T T i have edited some parts of your suggestion as -> df2 = pd.get_dummies(pd.merge(df, df2).set_index(cols)
df2 = df2[~df2.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
df2.groupby(col).sum() 
but, some data are still missing T T

Comment: @Sujin what do you mean by `missing`?

Comment: sorry for my english, i mean some data is disappeared

Comment: @Sujin use  `how='outer'` as arg in your `pd.merge`. Check edited